# Deploying Meteor App to own server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a completed meteor project and is currently deployed on the meteor website. I would like to move it to my own website, which is currently hosted by GoDaddy.

How do I install Node and Mongo on my server (linux) and then run my meteor project? I received ssh access to my server, so I assume I can do this, but I'm just not sure how.

So how exactly do I proceed?

Additional Info:

I'm not exactly sure what of linux it is. On GoDaddy, it simply says linux.

When I ssh, it shows me:

-bash-3.2$:

Also, I having my website simply show the myapp.meteor.com webpage would work too. An explanation on how to do this would work.

Comment: that depends on the kind of linux you are running. Is it ubuntu?

Comment: more generally though, just look for install instructions for node and then for mongodb, and then just follow the deploy instruction in the meteor documentation, no?

Answer (score 3):

[Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) has a chapter on deployment which helps to answer this question. For ubuntu-based servers they recommend [meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up). I haven't used it, but it's probably worth checking out. Previous versions of the book recommended [meteoric](https://github.com/julien-c/meteoric.sh).

I wrote my own set of bash scripts using a few ideas from meteoric, but I already had a lot of experience doing deployment scripting. Frankly there's nothing quite like figuring it all out yourself, but doing sysadmin tasks doesn't appeal to everyone and it can be hard to pick up in a hurry.

Comment: meteor-up is simple and powerful!