# "meteor run --production" with MONGO_URL vs. bundling

Tags: node.js, meteor, docker

Perhaps my question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316344/meteor-vs-meteor-bundle-for-production) but I feel it adds some specifics that make it differ somewhat.

I currently have a Meteor Docker setup, based on the node:0.10 image, that first bundles the app and runs "node main.js" as its CMD. The image also installs Meteor and uses its command to bootstrap the environment and install necessary packages.

It occurs to me that the image would be vastly simplified if, instead of using node:0.10, I could use a more minimal Linux image and simply install curl/git/meteor. Removing the build step would further simplify things, since based on my understanding "meteor build" has no means to not build mobile apps if they're configured but not needed (I.e. if I normally build Android/IOS apps, I can't easily *not* build them if I just want a bundle). Further, my development environment already uses MONGO_URL and a containerized MongoDB instance, so I'm not even using a local database when developing.

So, what is the difference between "meteor run --production" with a set MONGO_URL, and "node main.js"? What happens in one instance that doesn't in the other?

In particular, does "meteor run --production" detect the presence of MONGO_URL and not spin up a separate, unused mongod? I clearly see data in the database pointed to by MONGO_URL but I'm not sure if the meteor command spins up a separate one that sits around and wastes CPU cycles/RAM. Based on the previous question, I gather it still polls the filesystem for changes. But does this just use inotify under Linux, and am I correct in assuming that's a fairly minor performance hit?

I imagine that, if I needed every ounce of performance out of my servers, bundling is the way to go. But if running "meteor run --production" with MONGO_URL set only incurs a minor performance hit while vastly simplifying my setup, it's probably worth it to me to simplify my Dockerfiles and unify my dev/production setup a bit more closely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A point to note is that `meteor run --production` ... means "run in an development environment that simulates production" and not "this is how you should run your app in production".

So process.env.NODE_ENV is set to `development` when you run above command.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/180#issuecomment-30043150

Answer (score 1):

Any `meteor` command does use the database specified by `MONGO_URL`, and that database alone. I routinely point `MONGO_URL` to a blank string when running [`meteor test-packages`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteortestpackages) to avoid the overhead of spinning up a Mongo instance if the package doesn't do anything database-related. For peace of mind, you can double check that by running [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) in another terminal and seeing that no mongo processes are created.

Regarding `meteor run --production` monitoring the filesystem for changes, yes, that's a minor CPU overhead. Again htop can help.

> "meteor build" has no means to not build mobile apps if they're configured but not needed (I.e. if I normally build Android/IOS apps, I can't easily not build them if I just want a bundle)

In a pre-build step, you can easily replace .meteor/platforms to say just `server\nbrowser` (remove the `android` and `ios` lines) if you don't need the mobile platforms.

An advantage to bundling then running `node main.js` is that you can use pm2 (a [better alternative to forever](http://devo.ps/blog/goodbye-node-forever-hello-pm2/)) to keep your application running instead of crashes. However, see also [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up).

Comment: So how to "deploy" a new version with `node.main.js` via hotcode pushes?

Comment: @DotNetWise: You can use [`meteor build`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteorbuild) to generate the new version (the target directory contents are overwritten), then  [`pm2`](http://devo.ps/blog/goodbye-node-forever-hello-pm2/) `restart` to restart `node.main.js`. Check out also [meteor up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up).

Comment: I have tried mup, but I'm totally dissapointed. It doesn't even install correctly