# Meteor bundle vs meteor --production

Tags: node.js, meteor, bundle, production-environment

I am facing dilema whether I should bundle node js app from meteor or just run meteor --production.

I am mostly interested in performance impact. I have found some explanation on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316344/meteor-vs-meteor-bundle-for-production), but it is not clearly stated that meteor runs in production mode.

Running just meteor --production will simplify my deployment process a lot.

I would like to know are there any reasons to stick to bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you run `meteor --production`, you are still running as if you are in development-mode, only using "production" settings and such.  You are still getting an internal/local MongoDB, you are still burning CPU time monitoring files, etc.

If this is true, then the end result is that you will not scale at all.  I doubt that running local MongoDB uses optlog, which is a HUGE performance boost for Meteor apps.

Your best bet would be to look at some automated build/deploy tools.  I have personally used mup and mupx.  The latest version of mup builds your app, sets up MongoDB (if you want) and nginx, builds them all as docker images, and deploys them.  You can even setup SSL certs w/ nginx (although no Let's Encrypt support yet :().  Or, you could easily script the deployment yourself using any number of tools, including just raw scripts.  I think in the long run you will be in much better shape than trying to run the app using the meteor command.

Comment: Then what woumd be the purpose of production mode

Comment: To test your code without debug apps, like Meteor Tools and all of the test cases?